# File text change detection with rxjava

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I want to implement some code that detect any file change (txt, doc, pdf etc.) to trigger some task with RXJava. Is it possible? Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: use a FileObserver

Comment: It also works with no structured data such as xlsx or similar?

Comment: @Mike_Jr `FileObserver` is a class from the Android API. In this question there's no information or tag indicating that the task is Android-specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's possible. I'd do that in the following way:

- Use [FileAlterationObserver](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/monitor/FileAlterationObserver.html) from the [Apache Commons I/O](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/)
  library
- Create new observer basing on the documentation linked above
  (you can filter a concrete file if you don't want to monitor whole
  directory)
- In the observer you can use [FileAlterationListener](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/monitor/FileAlterationListener.html), which has methods like `onFileChange(File)` required for this task
- Create a method returning RxJava `Flowable` (backpressure-aware) or `Observable` type, which wraps listener created above - this will require some RxJava knowledge - you'll need to invoke `onNext(...)` method on the `Emitter` inside the `Flowable` implementation and define the type, you need to return within the `Flowable` - e.g. `Flowable<FileEvent>` where `FileEvent` have to be defined